# Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected error

Tags: php

I managed to get every other error ironed out, but I am stuck with this error! For the life of me, I cannot seem to diagnose where I went wrong. Any help from you brilliant people out there would be amazing!

I made a form editing php where it is supposed to edit a submission made into the system. This is then processed by my processing php but for some reason I am getting a "header may not contain more than a single header" error in my form submission. I changed the header code multiple times but I do not know why I am still getting it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogc8T.jpg

Edit:
Also wanted to add that this code was working fine for about a month. The only thing I changed was updating the hosting service platform from PHP 7.3 -> PHP 7.4. I tried reverting and it exactly the same error.

```
 if($_POST['form_submitted'] == 'editgroupreferral'){

            include("../../inc/inc.con.php");

            /* assign values to checkboxes  */
            if(isset($_POST['OtherServices'])){
                $otherservices = 1;
                } else {
                $otherservices = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['Medication'])){
                $medication = 1;
                } else {
                $medication = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['HaveAllergies'])){
                $allergies = 1;
                } else {
                $allergies = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['Device'])){
                $device = 1;
                } else {
                $device = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['Share'])){
                $share = 1;
                } else {
                $share = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['TakeTurns'])){
                $taketurns = 1;
                } else {
                $taketurns = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['Wait'])){
                $wait = 1;
                } else {
                $wait = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['MultInstructions'])){
                $multinstr = 1;
                } else {
                $multinstr = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['SitChair'])){
                $sitchair = 1;
                } else {
                $sitchair = 0;
                }

            if(isset($_POST['Routine'])){
                $routine = 1;
                } else {
                $routine = 0;
                }

            /* insert vars from form into ReferralSC table */
            $sql = "UPDATE ReferralGR SET
                    ReferrerName = :refname,
                    ReferrerRelationship = :refrelationship,
                    ReferrerPhone = :refphone,
                    ReferrerEmail = :refemail,
                    ReferMethod = :refmethod,
                    RefSupport = :refsupp,
                    OtherServices = :otherservices,
                    School = :school,
                    Diagnosis = :diagnosis,
                    Medication = :medication,
                    MedicationList = :medicationlist,
                    HaveAllergies = :allergies,
                    AllergiesList = :allergieslist,
                    Device = :device,
                    Share = :share,
                    TakeTurns = :taketurns,
                    Wait = :wait,
                    MultInstructions = :multinstr,
                    SitChair = :sitchair,
                    Routine = :routine,
                    ExplainFurther = :explain,
                    HeardAbout = :heardabout,
                    RefNotes = :notes
                    WHERE ref_id = :grid";

            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $s->bindvalue(':refname', $_POST['ReferrerName']);
            $s->bindvalue(':refrelationship', $_POST['ReferrerRelationship']);
            $s->bindvalue(':refphone', $_POST['ReferrerPhone']);
            $s->bindvalue(':refemail', $_POST['ReferrerEmail']);
            $s->bindvalue(':refmethod', $_POST['ReferMethod']);
            $s->bindvalue(':refsupp', $_POST['RefSupport']);
            $s->bindvalue(':otherservices', $otherservices);
            $s->bindvalue(':school', $_POST['School']);
            $s->bindvalue(':diagnosis', $_POST['Diagnosis']);
            $s->bindvalue(':medication', $medication);
            $s->bindvalue(':medicationlist', $_POST['MedicationList']);
            $s->bindvalue(':allergies', $allergies);
            $s->bindvalue(':allergieslist', $_POST['AllergiesList']);
            $s->bindvalue(':device', $device);
            $s->bindvalue(':share', $share);
            $s->bindvalue(':taketurns', $taketurns);
            $s->bindvalue(':wait', $wait);
            $s->bindvalue(':multinstr', $multinstr);
            $s->bindvalue(':sitchair', $sitchair);
            $s->bindvalue(':routine', $routine);
            $s->bindvalue(':explain', $_POST['ExplainFurther']);
            $s->bindvalue(':heardabout', $_POST['HeardAbout']);
            $s->bindvalue(':notes', $_POST['RefNotes']);
            $s->bindvalue(':grid', $_POST['ref_id']);

            $s->execute();

            header('location:../refer_gr/referral-view.php?rid=' . $_POST['ref_id'] );                  
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps there is something in `$_POST['ref_id']` - try using `trim($_POST['ref_id'])` on the header line just in case.

Comment: Just tried it, and it still gives me the same error. Thank you for helping out, I appreciate your time!

Comment: `trim` would only remove newlines from the beginning or end, not if it occurs somewhere in the middle of the value. Check what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this one was a toughie but I figured it out. Here is my method:

1. So the clue lies in the error itself. It was pointing me from my processing php. But it was only because the data being asked in the header (requires a reference ID) is wrong.
2. The problem was in the reference ID (after much debugging). It was taking the wrong value from the wrong variable. This was in the php form page not the php processing page.

So here is the solution:

```
$s->bindvalue(':refid', $refid);
```

Rest of the code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="<?php echo $rid; ?>" >
```

The variable `$rid` is not the same as the variable `$refid`.

Here is the fix:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="<?php echo $refid; ?>" >
```

This means that with this type of error, it might be worth looking at which part of the code it is trying to get the value from and start debugging from there.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This warning occurs to indicate that you might have a new line [/n] in the string content of your variables. The solution is to strip out the passable new line contents of the variable Like this

```
$val=$_POST['ref_id'];
$url="../refer_gr/referral-view.php?rid='$val'";
$url=str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $url);
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Hello Vishal K, thank you for taking the time and helping out. I have implemented the code and the result is still the same. Do you think I'm probably not looking at the right php page in question? Here is the code for the form that I am making (it has no errors unlike what it shows in the CodePen link. This is because it interacts and connects with my MySQL Database) https://codepen.io/AYSCodePen/pen/KKWdgxR